# not in rewhere active record rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

How can I use the 'not' together with the 'rewhere' statement in active_record?

bad example (not working):

```
Field.where(name: 'Bukk').rewhere.not(name: 'Tolgy')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to [`unscope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-unscope) your name condition and add it again:

```
Field.where(name: 'Bukk').unscope(where: :name).where.not(name: 'Tolgy')
```

[`rewhere`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-rewhere) uses `unscope` to do its work anyway.